# Sets of natural numbers closed under addition of successors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, computational-mathematics, conjectures

Conjecture:

> Given integers $0<a_1<a_2,\dots\,$ without a common divisor, such that all sums $\sum_{k=r}^q a_k\in A=\{a_1,a_2,\dots\}$. Then there is an integer $N$ such that for all integers $n>N$ it holds that $n\in A$.

I would like to see a proof or a counter-example.

I have computationally investigated some minimal sets $A$ as above which includes the primes or the squares or the exponents of two or the faculties, and *it seems like* $\,\mathbb Z_+\!\!\setminus\! A\,$ always is a finite set.

If $A$ is such a set that is minimal including the primes, then 
$\{n\in A|n \leq 97\}=$
$\{2,3,5,7,8,10,11,12,13,15,17,18,19,20,21,23,24,25,26,28,29,30,31,32,33,35,36,$   $37,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,56,57,58,59,60,61,63,64,$  $65,66,67,68,69,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,$  $91,92,93,94,95,96,97\}$

And if $A$ is the minimal set including the faculty numbers 
$1,2,6,24,120,\dots\,$ then $\{n\in A|n \leq 120\}=$ 
$\{1,2,3,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,14,16,17,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,$
$33,34,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,59,60,$
$61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,$  $86,87,88,89,90,91,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,$  $110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120\}$

Comment: Can you give a small example?

Comment: The condition in yellow, if I understood correctly, carries in itself a fatal contradiction: if such a $\;N\in\Bbb N\;$ actually exists, then $\;A\;$ will contain $\;N+1\;$ **and also** $\;2(N+1)\;$ , contradicting the fact that the elements in $\;A\;$ are pairwise coprime...

Comment: @Nitin: All examples are infinite and I have only investigated finite subsets of those sets.

Comment: @DonAntonio Maybe I'm wrong, but I understood the condition to mean that there's no integer greater than $1$ which simultaneously divides *all* the members of $A.$

Comment: @DonAntonio: the elements are not pairwise coprime, but there is no number that divide all the elements.

Comment: @MitchellSpector That's a good point...though in an infinite set of integers that would be almost a moot condition, as it is enough to have two consecutive integers there for *that* condition to be fulfilled...but perhaps you're right.

Comment: @DonAntonio I thought the purpose was to eliminate, for instance, the set of even numbers as a counterexample.